# Owin self host console application with https support (no web api, no SignalR)

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

With SslStream and socket, I've developed a https web server from scratch.
I can apply a certificate to the stream from C# code and deal with the requests.

However, I didn't figure out how to do this with Owin.
Does any one know how to bind a certificate to a self hosted console application?

*Example:*

```
// Bind the below certificate to Owin host
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("server.pfx", "password");
```

Please refer to the existing Owin host code below for details:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using AppFunc = System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;

namespace Owin.Startup
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int port = 8888;
            string url = $"http://localhost:{port}";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Hosted: {url}");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        private IAppBuilder app;
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
#if DEBUG
            app.UseErrorPage();
#endif

            app.Use(new Func<AppFunc, AppFunc>(next => (async env =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Begin Request");
                foreach (var i in env.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i}\t={(env[i] == null ? "null" : env[i].ToString())}\t#\t{(env[i] == null ? "null" : env[i].GetType().FullName)}");
                }
                if (next != null)
                {
                    await next.Invoke(env);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Process Complete");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("End Request");
            })));

            app.UseWelcomePage("/");

            this.app = app;
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Owin self hosting applications just need to bind to the proper URLs in code, while the certificate mappings should be done separately via Windows HTTP API.

`netsh http show sslcert` can show you the existing mappings, and [Jexus Manager](https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/https-binding.html#ip-based-bindings) provides the UI.