# how to enable https for owin self-host webapi

Tags: c#, https, owin

I met this error `IDX21323 OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was nul` and per my searching, it required to use `https` instead of `http`.

We can follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api#create-a-console-application) to create a self-host webapi use OWIN, but the base url is `http`.

So requirement is enable https for the url. Then how to do it?

I had my way below, but I also want to know a normal way for enabling `https`...

Thanks for any other advice!

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api#ssl-client-certificates), I can use `makecert.exe` to create a self-signed certificate but I don't know why after I followed the doc to add certificate to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`, the certificate didn't appear in the list.(Maybe it require a reboot?)

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=Development CA" -r -sv TempCA.pvk TempCA.cer
makecert.exe -pe -ss My -sr CurrentUser -a sha1 -sky exchange -n "CN=name" 
     -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -sk SignedByCA -ic TempCA.cer -iv TempCA.pvk
```

[image]

But it made me find there's a certificate issued `localhost` in the list.

I remembered it is generated by Visual Studio. When we use IIS Express to run the web application via Visual Studio, it will generate it for us. So I want to use it for my Owin api. Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49952316). It informed me that I don't need to do any changes in my code, I only need to run a `netsh` command to bind the certificate to the port.

Then this is [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate#bind-an-ssl-certificate-to-a-port-number) about how to use command to bind the port with certificate.

And this is the command I used. Getting thrumbprint from certificate and generate guid from an online tool.

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8099 certhash=5c50eaxxxxxxz29daea9 appid={ad9f5133-25cd-412a-974c-059bbde7cb3e}
```

[image]